# Can I override just part of an ActiveAdmin controller action using `super` + custom redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, activeadmin, monkeypatching

I've registered a Widget in ActiveAdmin and want to change the redirect that takes place after creating a new one. So that I can accomplish various things with Javascript, I've created a custom form for creating/editing them such that in `/admin/widget.rb` I have this:

```
  form do |f|
    render "create_or_edit_widget"
  end
```

I want to modify the basic `Admin::WidgetsController#create` action to change where the user is redirected after successfully creating one. I can fill out the rest of the custom action to complete this, except I don't know how to handle a case where the `.save` fails and the user is redirected back to the form *with* the formtastic inline error messages. I know how I could do this if I wanted the normal Rails form behavior of creating a list of error messages but not enough about Formtastic to copy its behavior. So far I have this:

```
controller do 
  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(params[:widget])
    if @widget.save
      redirect_to admin_widgets_path, notice: "Successfully created Widget."
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end
end
```

I was wondering if I can somehow user `super` and then *only* change the redirect path after successful creation instead of having to write out the entire action. If that's not possible, can anyone tell me where in the ActiveAdmin GitHub I'd be able to find the standard `#create` action so I can copy it out and change the one part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Here is a working code from my application using super and just changing the redirection

```
def create
  super do |format|
    redirect_to admin_submission_discussion_path(id: resource.discussion.slug, submission_id: resource.discussion.client_application.slug) and return if resource.valid?
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Before, I was doing something similar but getting a double redirect error because my redirect was being added to the parent controller rather than replacing its redirect. It seems that adding `and return if resource.valid?` is what fixes it for me. Do you know why that makes the difference?